# Rotate Video/MediaPlayer in a TextureView

Tags: android, video, layout, camera, android-mediarecorder

I'm working with camera2 and I'm showing a preview of my photo/video after longclick in my thumbnail. Also, I'm rotating it depending of which orientation the camera had when the picture was taken. For example, if I did a picture in 90º, my preview will be also rotated 90º.

Everything is working fine, I'm using a customContainer and there I'm using onLayout and OnMeasure to create my preview depending of the size of the screen, aspect ratio and orientation. It works fine with photos. My problem appear when I try to do the same with videos, they only work in 0º.

I tried to rotate the TextureView which contain my MediaPlayer but after this my onLayout become crazy and Itś impossible find a (l,t,r,b) combination to measure it correctly.

Here is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<com.android.camera.ui.common.ThumbnailContainer xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/preview_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_rectangle_thumbnail_preview"
    android:visibility="invisible">



<TextureView
    android:id="@+id/show_video_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="invisible"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:visibility="invisible"

/>
</com.android.camera.ui.common.ThumbnailContainer>
```

Here is my Surface code:

```
    @Override
    public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {
        Log.i(TAG, "InicializoSurface. Width: " + width + "  HEIGHT:" + height);
        Log.i(TAG, "InicializoSurface. Width: " + mVideoView.getMeasuredWidth() + "  HEIGHT:" + mVideoView.getMeasuredHeight());
        Log.i(TAG, "View transform. Width: " + mVideoView.getWidth() + "  HEIGHT:" + mVideoView.getHeight());


        mMediaSurface = new Surface(mVideoView.getSurfaceTexture());
        initializeMediaPlayer();

    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture surface) {

        if (mMediaPlayer != null) {
            // Make sure we stop video and release resources when activity is destroyed.
            mMediaPlayer.stop();
            mMediaPlayer.release();
            mMediaPlayer = null;
        }
        return false;
    }
    @Override
    public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture surface) {

    }
    //////////
     private void initializeMediaPlayer(){

        mMediaPlayer = new CustomMediaPlayer();
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(mCameraDataAdapter.getList().get(0).getPath());

        try {
            mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(mActivity, uri);
            mMediaPlayer.setSurface(mMediaSurface);
            mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
            mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(mMediaPlayer);
            mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(mMediaPlayer);


        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }


       ///////////
        mVideoView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

//                    mVideoView.setTranslationX(-200);
//                    mVideoView.setTranslationY(-200);
                    Log.i(TAG, "X: " + mVideoView.getX() + "Y: " + mVideoView.getY());


                    if (mVideoView.isAvailable()) {
                        onSurfaceTextureAvailable(mVideoView.getSurfaceTexture(), mVideoView.getWidth(), mVideoView.getHeight());
                    }

                    if (mMediaPlayer == null) {
                        initializeMediaPlayer();
                    }

//                    mMediaPlayer.mVideoHolder = mVideoView.getHolder();
//                    mMediaPlayer.setDisplay(mMediaPlayer.mVideoHolder);

                    if (mMediaPrepared) {
                        Log.i(TAG,"Comienzo Video");
                        mMediaPlayer.start();
                    }
```

Finally here is my onMeasure/OnLayout from my CustomView

```
      @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {

        int width;
        int height;
        int wantedWidth = 0;
        int wantedHeight = 0;

        if(mWidth == 0 && mHeight == 0 ){
            mWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
            mHeight =MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
        }

        width = mWidth;
        height = mHeight;





        if (mOrientation == 0 || mOrientation == 180) {

            wantedWidth = width  - (int)(mMargin * 2);

            mVideo.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(wantedWidth, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY), MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec((int) (wantedWidth * mVideoAspectRatio), MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));
            wantedHeight = (mViewTop.getLayoutParams().height) * 2 + (int) (wantedWidth * mAspectRatio);

        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "Real Width = " + width + " real Height = " + height);

            wantedHeight = width - 2 * mViewTop.getLayoutParams().height - (int)(mMargin * 2);

            mVideo.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(wantedHeight, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec((int) (wantedHeight * mAspectRatio), MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));
//         
            wantedWidth =(int) (wantedHeight * mAspectRatio) ;
            wantedHeight =  width - (int)(mMargin * 2);


        }

        Log.e(TAG, "onMeasure: " + wantedWidth + "x" + wantedHeight);
        setMeasuredDimension(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(wantedWidth, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY), MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(wantedHeight, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
        int w = getMeasuredWidth();
        int h = getMeasuredHeight();

        int viewHeight = mViewBottom.getMeasuredHeight();
        int imageViewHeight = mImage.getMeasuredHeight();

        int wantedHeight = 0;
//        w = w - (int) (2 * mMargin);
        if (mOrientation == 0 || mOrientation == 180) {

            mVideo.layout(0,wantedHeight,w,wantedHeight + imageViewHeight);


        }else{               
            mVideo.layout(viewHeight,0,r-viewHeight - (int) mMargin,w);
        }
    }
```

I have been looking in other post as [Android MediaRecorder making rotated video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12252927/android-mediarecorder-making-rotated-video) and I saw that it's not possible to rotate the textureView, but I can't believe that I can rotate a image so easily and have to fight during this to rotate 90 degrees a video.

Comment: use `TextureView#setTransform(Matrix transform)`

Comment: @pskink I already tryed to use a Matrix with SetTransform and it doesnt do nothing. I tryed it before measure everything, when I call the Surface or when I pick the photo. The video dont change, it stay exactly as before :S

Comment: `setTransform` just works, i used that many times, basically your `Matrix` is computed in a wrong way

Comment: VideoView does not support rotation of video even if composition matrix is set correctly and rotation attribute is used. I already tried this mate. 

If you think that it really work I will really appreciate if you can give me a Matrix computed in a good way to rotate 90º or 270º a TextureView

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8586526/rotating-an-android-videoview

Comment: are we talking about `VideoView` or  `TextureView` ?

Comment: My mistake. Im talking about a TextureView. But also i have been looking for it and it only work if I use a setOrientation(X) over the View. If I do this the video is rotated but the onMeasure and onLayout explode in pieces xD

Comment: btw, you dont need any custom views with overridden `onMeasure` / `onLayout`, just correct `Matrix` is good enough

Comment: ok, just found the code for `Matrix` setup: http://pastebin.com/HVr1XyaT

Comment: Im just trying to use the last example that you sent me mate, relax. Im not going to answer you without test anything.

Comment: Lets go to a chat room if you want, it will be easier I think

Comment: Im sorry, im at chat room. Waiting u there

Comment: Its working! thx mate! Put an answer to check it as correct and close the question!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thanks to @pskink for their comments in the post I found a solution with him. Finally I used a Matrix to rotate the Video Container(Texture View). The method that pskink give me is the next one:

```
  private void setupMatrix(int width, int height, int degrees, boolean isHorizontal) {
    Log.d(TAG, "setupMatrix for " + degrees + " degrees");
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    //The video will be streched if the aspect ratio is in 1,5(recording at 480)
    RectF src;
    if (isHorizontal)
//In my case, I changed this line, because with my onMeasure() and onLayout() methods my container view is already rotated and scaled, so I need to sent the inverted params to the src.
        src = new RectF(0, 0,mThumbnailContainer.getmWidth(), mThumbnailContainer.getmHeight());
        else
        src = new RectF(0, 0, mThumbnailContainer.getmWidth(),mThumbnailContainer.getmHeight());
    RectF dst = new RectF(0, 0, width, height);
    RectF screen = new RectF(dst);
    Log.d(TAG, "Matrix: " + width + "x" + height);
    Log.d(TAG, "Matrix: " + mThumbnailContainer.getmWidth() + "x" + mThumbnailContainer.getmHeight());
    matrix.postRotate(degrees, screen.centerX(), screen.centerY());
    matrix.mapRect(dst);

    matrix.setRectToRect(src, dst, Matrix.ScaleToFit.CENTER);
    matrix.mapRect(src);

    matrix.setRectToRect(screen, src, Matrix.ScaleToFit.FILL);
    matrix.postRotate(degrees, screen.centerX(), screen.centerY());

    mVideoView.setTransform(matrix);
}
```

Finally it worked and it looks totally awesome. With this I have been able to rotate and scale any video totally dynamically depending of the screen of my device and the Aspect Ratio used for record the video or take the picture.

Comment: i'm facing the same problem... could you explain me how to use your method? what is "mThumbnailContainer" and where this "width" and "height" come from. thanks

Comment: Why line         src = new RectF(0, 0,mThumbnailContainer.getmWidth(), mThumbnailContainer.getmHeight());
just dublicates with else statment